# Git: ¿Como puedo evitar reintroducir la contraseña cada que se abre o cierra la consola?

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

Verán desde hace tiempo tengo un problema con git bash, el cual es que cada que abro la consola y hago `git commit` y `git push` tengo que introducir mi contraseña de GPG y SSH.

Obviamente solo lo hago una vez por cada vez que abro la consola y hago `git commit` y `git push`.

Pero me gustaría saber si es posible almacenar la contraseña  de GPG y de SSH, para ingresarla cada que abro la consola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo le habia puesto una "frase"  al configurarlo y me la pedia cada que hacia algun push pull etc.

Si ese es tu caso solo ingresa

```
ssh-keygen -p
```

Y debe dejar de pedirte esa frase de seguridad.

Answer (score 1):

Me sé algunos métodos, te los pongo a continuación.

### Guardar los datos directamente

```
git config --global user.name "your username"

git config --global user.password "your password"
```

Es el más fácil y rápido, sin embargo tu usuario y contraseña se guardan como texto en tu sistema, lo cual puede ser un riesgo a futuro.

### Guardar los datos en cache

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

Este es menos inseguro que el anterior ya que el timeout en segundos es el tiempo en que tardará en borrarse, pero igual se siguen guardando como texto plano

### Crar en Github

Para el caso particular de github, ellos pueden generarla, solamente debes de agregarla mediante el comando

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

O si tu ide lo soporta agregarla mediante algún plugin como lo hace el [intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea)

Para generarla ve a github.com -> Settings -> SSH and GPG keys -> New SSH Key

[image: pantalla de configuración github ssh]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que configurar tu Git para usar SSH....Espera que te paso la información. Supongo que usas Github, aunque personalmente prefiero Bitbucket ya que funciona prácticamente igual con la salvedad que te permite tener repositorios privados aun en la cuenta gratuita cosa que Github no permite.

Básicamente debes:

```
1. Generar las claves SSH en tu maquina (IMPORTANTE: si no quieres que te pida la clave la generas sin contraseña)
2. La instalas en tu proveedor Git.
3. Y así cada vez que accedas a la consola no te pide la contraseña.
```

En este enlace te lo explican mas detalladamente:

[Instalar SSH en Github](https://help.github.com/es/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)

POST EDICION: Pues si ya lo tenias configurado y te sigue pidiendo la contraseña debes crear otras claves SSH para sustituir a las que tienes actualmente y cuando te pida contraseña al crearla dile que las crees sin contraseña así te ahorras tener que escribirla una vez por sesión.

Comment: Permiteme corregirte, github ya permite repsitorios privados aún en cuenta gratuita, yo tengo uno así

Comment: UUppppps siii????no lo sabia. Gracias por la información.

Comment: Ya lo tengo configurado desde hace tiempo y de echo no es lo que pregunte. Y coincido con @BetaM

Comment: Los repos privados en Github están tiempo operativos para las cuentas gratuitas...